# FIR filter design with nonlinear phase from measured amplitude and phase responses

Tags: filters, filter-design, finite-impulse-response, least-squares

I am having trouble when design FIR filter fitting to the complex data (i.e., amplitude and phase responses from measurements). I did try to use Matt. L's lslevin method [here](https://gist.github.com/mattdsp/fa287e57813950f4454fd3e90aa383b1) since this method is to deal with arbitrary prescribed amplitude and phase. However, it seems that I cannot get the appropriate real time-domain coefficients. You may run the Matlab script to check the results.

The issues I did encounter were that **the amplitude and phase estimated from lslevin result present huge errors compared to the original measured data**.

I have also checked with various design method listed in Matt. L. PhD thesis, but I still have not found a solution.

It would be great help if you have any suggestions or solutions. 
Thank you very much.

Matlab script for illustration:

```matlab
% FIR filter design using LS method with arbitrary amp. & phase resp.
% (nonlinear phase)
clc;close all;clear all

%% setups & measurement results
fs = 16e9;
fn = 31/4096*fs:125e6:2047/4096*fs;
f_norm = 2*pi*fn/fs;
fn_intp = linspace(f_norm(1),f_norm(end),512);
amp0 = [0.6100 0.6082 0.5949 0.6309 0.6582 0.6482 0.6775];
phs0 = [0.0465 0.0465 0.2740 0.8148 1.0403 1.8896 2.5158];
f_meas = [f_norm(1) f_norm(14) f_norm(20) f_norm(35) f_norm(45) f_norm(55) f_norm(end)];

% interpolation to have dense data
amp = interp1(f_meas,amp0,fn_intp,'spline');
phs = interp1(f_meas,phs0,fn_intp,'spline');
figure;plot(fn_intp,amp);figure;plot(fn_intp,phs);

%% Test with Matt. L.'s alg.
D = amp.*exp(1j*phs);% desired response
W = [ones(1,32) ones(1,448) ones(1,32)];% weighted 
tap_num = 11;
h = lslevin(tap_num,fn_intp,D,W); % please download the lslevin function
figure;stem(h,'linewidth',2);grid on;xlabel('Index');ylabel('Amp.')

% plot to check
[A,F] = freqz(h,1,512);
figure;plot(fn_intp,amp);grid on
hold on;plot(F,abs(A));xlabel('Norm freq. (rad./sample)');ylabel('Amp.')
legend('Original','LS results')
figure;plot(fn_intp,phs);grid on
hold on;plot(F,angle(A));xlabel('Norm freq. (rad./sample)');ylabel('rad.')
legend('Original','LS results')
```

Comment: If your script requires a download then please add a (legal) download link.

Comment: Hi Hilmar, I did include the link (within the question, 1st paragraph) shared from Matt. L. in GitHub.

Comment: Sorry, my bad !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The algorithm gives you the best least squares approximation possible for a *causal* filter with the specified filter order and the given desired frequency response. The problem with your specification is the desired phase response. It corresponds to a negative group delay almost throughout the entire band. Apart from that, a real-valued filter must have a phase of zero or $\pm\pi$ at DC and at Nyquist, which the given phase response doesn't satisfy either.

If you really need to approximate the given phase response, the only option for obtaining a reasonable approximation with a causal filter is to add a linear phase to the desired phase. This just means that the filter adds some delay apart from approximating the desired phase response. This is usually no problem, and in this case there's no other option anyway.

I tried this by adding the following lines to your code (after the interpolation of the data):

```
del = 15;
phs = phs - fn_intp * del;
```

This adds a linear phase for a specified delay `del`. I also increased the number of taps to $31$.

`tap_num = 31;`

Note that the extra delay `del` should be adapted to the number of taps, i.e., if you want to increase the number of taps you should also increase the delay.

The figures below shows the approximation after these changes. The top figure shows the desired and actual magnitude responses, and the bottom plot shows the phase approximation error. The result is still not great because the phase at Nyquist is not what a real-valued filter can realize.

[image]

The result can be further improved by changing the phase specification at Nyquist such that the phase remains smooth but that its value at Nyquist equals an integer multiple of $\pi$, which is what a real-valued filter can satisfy. The phase value closest to the one specified at Nyquist is $\pi$. Changing the definition of `phs0` to

`phs0 = [0.0465 0.0465 0.2740 0.8148 1.0403 1.8896 pi];`

changes the result significantly. With `del=15` and `tap_num=31` the design results are shown in the figure below:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, thank you very much for you time and clear explanations. It's very helpful to me. I think I will modify the phase near the Nyquist as your suggestion to trade for the ripple improvement in the considered band. One more option is that we can optimize the weight to reduce the ripple in the considered frequency band.
Besides, from your experience, are there any other approaches better than this least square approximation using Levinson method? Thanks.

Comment: @user190055: Looking at the last plot in my answer, what do you think could or should be improved?

Comment: I think they are reducing the tap numbers and lowering complexity comparing to the LS Levinson. Thanks.

Comment: @user190055: Now that you have a better specification, you can try other methods. But I doubt that there's much to be gained. You can decrease the filter order with lslevin and see if the approximation is still satisfactory. In that case you also should reduce the delay `del`. A good starting point for the delay is approximately half the filter length (number of taps).

Comment: Got it, thank you.